# Split String results in uneven array item lengths due to trailing delimiters

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

Usually when you split a string such as `Hi,One,Two` you will get back 3 delimited items.

However when you need the extra comma on the last item `Hi,One,Two,` you will get 4 items.

I am splitting a string into a string array and finding the array item lengths are uneven due to the extra delimiters at the end of the string:

```
string test = "[one]\t\t\t[two]\t\t\t";
string[] testArr = test.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

It results in:

[0] = "[one]"
[1] = ""
[2] = ""              **<- missing the 4th item**
[3] = "[two]"
[4] = ""
[5] = ""
[6] = ""          <- it has the 4th item

**Is there any way of not having to add the forth comma for all segments except the last?**

EDIT:

Sure I could easily use this code:

```
string test = "[one]\t\t\t\t[two]\t\t\t";
string[] testArr = test.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

And get the ideal result:

[0] = "[one]"
[1] = ""
[2] = ""
[3] = ""
[4] = "[two]"
[5] = ""
[6] = ""
[7] = ""

For purposes beyond this question I was hoping I could have equal trailing delimiters, rather than tweaking the string so that the last one has one less trailing comma.

Comment: Do you wish to ignore all empty entries? You can change StringSplitOptions.None to StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx

Comment: No, but thanks... in my question it's why I explicitly specified the `String.Split` overload that accepts StringSplitOptions. I cant use RemoveEmptyEntries as I need the trailing comma's for another operation/calculation, I think I'm going to have to put the forth comma in, unless someone knows some other trick. hmmm perhaps I should just split by `[` and then count the comma's.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but question doesn't really make sense - why are you expecting a 4th element if there's no comma there? Why isn't there a comma there? Where does this string come from? Just construct it with another comma...?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way of not having to add the forth comma for all segments
>   except the last?

`String.Split` works as it should, so you need another comma there to generate that extra index into the string. You have two options

1. Put the comma in before you `Split`
2. Add an empty element after you `Split`

I expect that there's more to this that you haven't included in the question.

Are you, for instance, joining `[one],,,` and `[two],,,`? If you are then you'd want to join them with a comma delimiter, rendering `[one],,,,[two],,,` (note the extra comma). Try to insert the comma earlier.

The biggest question is why are you concerned with carrying around empty strings in your array? Use a list, insert the extra strings if you need. Just add strings to the list when you actually need them, rather than carrying empties. Or use objects rather than collections of strings.

Comment: Thanks Kirk, the comma's are a poor example on my behalf, they are actually Tabs in this application. I need the tabs to represent a treeview where nodes are padded so the structure fits in a table. I'll just tweak the string.

Answer (score 1):

> I dont want to do this code and I cant get rid of the comma's at the
>   end:

Use [string.TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) to remove the trailing commas and then split your string based on the comma later.

```
string test = "[one],,,,[two],,,";
test = test.TrimEnd(',');
string[] testArr = test.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Or in one statement:

```
    string[] testArr2 = "[one],,,,[two],,,"
                               .TrimEnd(',')
                               .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Based on your edited question, your current code should give you the result you are looking for. Look at the following screenshot

[image]

Comment: @JeremyThompson, I am kind of confused, your current code gives you the exact ideal result ? is there something you are missing, let me add a screenshot to my answer

Comment: Thanks we are on the same page. Do you know anyway of getting that output using the string `[one],,,[two],,,` without tweaking the string.

Comment: @JeremyThompson, I am not doing anything with the string in my edited answer, see the screenshot, it is your code and I am just showing you the output from the debug, It is same as ideal result

Comment: +1 Thanks for your **help** <strong is two astrix's>. I'll just tweak the string or delimit by `[` and count comma's. I'm trying to do something that isn't supported out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

```
string test = "[one]\t\t\t[two]\t\t\t";
string[] arrUnEven = test.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.None);

test = test.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\t' });
test = test + new String( '\t',2);
string[] arrEven = test.Split(new char[] { '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```